# Ubuntu 17.10 WiFi is excruciatingly slow (Lenovo W540 Laptop, iwlwifi driver)

Tags: networking, lenovo, 17.10, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I'm getting 0.3 - 0.5 Mb/Sec (practically analog modem speeds!!!) with my WiFi as of late. This is a new problem that has cropped up lately. I've been using Ubuntu 17.10 for several months now without issues and then this started happening:

[WiFi Slowdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kn0V.png)

When I first start using my laptop, or after I reset my adapter (turn Wifi off and back on again), I get this:

[After Restarting WiFi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPIyb.png)

Still nothing to write home about (it should be in the 60+ Mbps range, as reported by my cell phone (android) on the same network:

[Expected WiFi (Cell phone on same network)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOApP.png)

I've tried turning hardware encryption off as described here [Very slow internet connection Wifi](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175345), but it does not help (note: I had to change the module name to my adapter - "iwlwifi"). So, I'm looking for suggestions. Here's my system info:

Lenovo W540 Laptop

Release: Ubuntu 17.10 (artful)

Kernel: 4.13.0-19-generic (#22-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 11:58:07 UTC 2017)

Network Controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b) - Wireless-N

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue with my W540 under Ubuntu 16.04, disabling 802.11n networking fixed it for me.

Add this to end of /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf and restart:

`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please use the markup for code, it makes the answers more readable, thanks!

Comment: This *partially* worked. It improved my download speed from 0.1 mbps to 21 mbps, but on my other laptop I'm getting 230 mbps

Comment: I m getting 21 mbps only